# Watching http in wireshark,what's the relation between reassembled TCP vs. Hypertext Transfer Protocol + Line-based text data?

Tags: wireshark, http-protocols

[image]

Though after verifying it I found `reassembled TCP segments` are the same as `Hypertext Transfer Protocol + Line-based text data`,but does wireshark count them twice?

Comment: This would be a good question for http://ask.wireshark.org .

Answer (score 1):

TCP provides the illusion of a continuous stream of data, but it's actually multiple packets over the wire.  A higher-level "protocol data unit" (PDU), such as an HTTP request or response, can be divided into multiple packets along arbitrary boundaries by the underlying TCP.

Wireshark reassembles PDUs that have been split up into multiple packets, so that they can be displayed meaningfully.  That HTTP response you see is being displayed in the details pane of a single packet, but it actually represents the combined contents of several packets.  The "Reassembled TCP Segments" section links to the other packets that contributed to this complete HTTP message, and if you follow those links, you'll probably find that the earlier packets are labeled "TCP segment of a reassembled PDU".

Comment: I agree with how *Reassembled TCP Segments* are composed,but what's the relation between this reassembled stuff and `Hypertext Transfer Protocol + Line-based text data`,why is it displayed twice by wireshark?

Comment: @mysql_go, the "Reassembled TCP Segments" are broken down by frame number, so that you can see which portions of the complete message were in which packets.  The "Hypertext Transfer Protocol" + "Line-based text data" is the same reassembled data, but broken down by protocol instead.  It's not two copies of the data, just two different ways of analyzing the same data.